# consistency of solution question

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Let $A, B$ be $n\times n$ matrices and $c, d$ be $n \times 1$ vectors such that the matrix equations
$$Ax = c$$

$$Bx = d$$
are consistent, i.e., each equation admits a solution. Can we conclude that
$$(A + B)x = (c + d)$$
is also consistent? Prove if true or give a counter example if not true.

i tried hard to find counter example but i coudnt find any

Comment: What if $\det (A+B)=0$, but $\det A\ne 0$ and $\det B\ne 0$?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just what Michael wrote. Counter example:  $A=1$, $B=-1$, $c=1$, $d=\pi$.